# Specified method is not supported when trying to read a ResponseStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read a responseStream to the end and getting an error "Specified method is not supported" in the br.ReadBytes line.

What am I doing wrong?

```
WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
{
    imageBytes = br.ReadBytes((int)responseStream.Length);
    br.Close();
}
```

Comment: I get: NotSupportedException: This stream does not support seek operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting error: NotSupportedException: This stream does not support seek 
operations.

why not making it a lot easier to get an image, assuming you want a byte array:

```
byte[] imageBytes
using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
    imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("http://yourimage");
}
```